# iPhone in-app SMS changes color of status bar while SMS modal view is presented

Tags: ios4, uiviewcontroller, sms, statusbar

I have a simple in app SMS view slide up when a button is pressed.

However in the Info.plist I have the status bar set to Opaque black style, but when the SMS view is shown the status bar changes to gray. And then changes back once the SMS view is dismissed.

this is the SMS code...

```
if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
{
    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

    NSString *MessageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@%@",Label2.text, Label4.text, Label1.text];

    controller.body = MessageString;

    controller.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

Has else anyone run into this?

Is there a way to have the SMS view not change the status bar color?

Answer (score 4):

Try this after you present the controller,

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
```

Comment: Used that line of code after the SMS view is shown and it works correctly now. Thanks.